# MVC Design - How many controllers can/should/must I have in a CodeIgniter MVC web app project?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm building a relatively simple web application in PHP using the CodeIgniter MVC framework. I've developed PHP applications before but never in a disciplined manner. I'm getting used to the MVC framework, however two questions keep bringing me back to the drawing board and it's slowing down development.

1. Is there a best practice on how many controllers a web app can have? I have one (fairly large) controller for my app that includes business logic, form submission logic, etc. While this *works*, I'm debating whether it would make sense to have separate controllers, e.g. one for form handling and submission, another for user management (session, login, sign up), etc. Then again, I don't want to overengineer the heck out of this either. **The part where I am getting hung up is:** the controller has a "default" index function that gets loaded at the parent URL. All the business logic starts off from here (e.g., form submission, doing something with the data, etc.). I've defaulted to just creating new functions in the same controller as development continued. It works, but part of my goal is to also learn the best practice and something tells me I may be going about this the wrong way.
2. Should models **only** be used for database read/write functions or can I put "helper" functions in there as well, e.g. generate_random_number, validate_login_credentials, login_session, logout_session, etc.

Comment: This is the cleanest, most well thought out & formatted **1 Reputation** Question I have ever seen. +1 for you good sir!

Comment: Shouldn't this be on "Programmers Exchange?" Good question though.

Answer (score 4):

(This is my subjective opinion - it has treated me well)

Models should be the meat and bone of your entire applications. The models should handle all business logic and database management. Meanwhile, the controllers should be as thin as possible, only really providing an interface between the model and view.

For instance, in a login screen, the controller should provide the user with the login view. When the user inputs his information, the controller should handle input validation and forward the input to the model, which should respond with "success" or "failure". Consequently the controller should redirect the user to the dashboard, or send him back to the login screen with an error message - respectively.

To summarize: **Models should be fat, controllers should be thin.**

Comment: Important to remember: **This answer is highly subjective** , Fat controller vs fat model is a debate for the ages, lets not present it as if one side or the other is a decided standard.  Codeigniter actually encourages fat controllers, different frameworks are built around different goals/ideas

Comment: @jondavidjohn: True for general MVC, but for PHP development the fat model skinny controllers approach is obviously the best approach. http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3856246/Fat-Models-and-Skinny--Controllers-Bring-Out-the-Best-in-Your-MVC-Framework.htm

Comment: this simply illustrates your lack of experience with codeigniter.  The example of form validation given in the article is not even possible with codeigniter as the Model class does not extend the singleton CI instance, therefore it can ***not*** perform validation, at least utilizing Codeigniter's validation library.  So, while it might be a good idea in frameworks that are built with this organization in mind, codeigniter was not.

Comment: I gave my answer as a PHP developer. I suppose that was my bad :P

Comment: @Codemonkey totaly agree with you. even with CI, example for problems that can happen from fat controller is inability to reuse your code because you cannt reference a controller action/property from anyother model/controller .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614905/codeigniter-mvc-should-i-move-my-business-logic-from-model-into-controller-to-u

Answer (score 2):

***Controllers***

It all depends upon the nature of the application, but in general the answer is ***NO*** you should not have "one fairly large controller".

The more you break an application up into smaller pieces, the easier it is to maintain.

***Models***

Directly from the Codeigniter docs

> Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in your database.

The answer is yes, you should only use models for data interaction.

I think it's funny you actually answered yourself

"... or can I put **'helper'** functions in there as well, ..."

It happens Codeigniter has a facility that handles this type of functionality...

[Codeigniter Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Comment: I can see why MVC would enforce disciplined coding. What you're suggesting is a "login controller" that calls functions in the "login helper" that uses the "login model" to validate user's credentials. Hmm, ouch!

Comment: No, generally for login functions you utilize (or write) a an library that would have a corresponding model that interacts with the database.  If you read the description of helper, It would be better suited for a task like your generate_random_number example.

Comment: I generally have a "auth" controller that handles login / logout / forgotten_password / etc... public facing auth functions, that would then send a user on to a protected area once the login is successful.  I've got a fairly detailed article on this topic http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth

Comment: Would you "more or less" have a controller for every model?