# is it better to have different controller and different model in MVC

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm new at the MVC model. Im still learning on how to use codeigniter framework.

So, i have some questions, is it better to have different controller and different model to perform some functions or is it better to combine all into one controller and one model?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735761/mvc-design-how-many-controllers-can-should-must-i-have-in-a-codeigniter-mvc-we

Answer (score 0):

It is all up to you. But consideration seems like having particular controller for one object like User or Article etc. Depending on controller you would like to have appropriate model for manipulating consisting data `User_model.php` or `Article_m.php`.

If you have some generic methods and code that you want to pull out from DB from many controllers, you might have something like `Generic_m.php`.

If you have some other functions related to some area you can make your own library and use those.

For simple functions that don'e belong to any specific set you can create your own helpers.