# Controllers in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I would like to know when it's the best to create a controller.

I mean why can't we just use 1 controller for all our functions.

For example I have this controller called `forumcontroller`

why can't I just put all my functions in that controller and then do something like.

```
forumcontroller@function1

forumcontroller@function2

forumcontroller@function3
```

When is it best to create a new one?

Comment: The point is to keep things simple and readable. But if you have 20 different forum-related methods, and you ask 20 different programmers, you're going to get wildly differing opinions on where and how you should stick all of them. This question is inevitably opinion-based. That's not to say it's a bad question - it's really a good one. Just not suitable for SO.

Comment: It is not about Laravel is about MVC good topic also on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735761/mvc-design-how-many-controllers-can-should-must-i-have-in-a-codeigniter-mvc-we

Comment: @JoelHinz Very clear!

Comment: @Froxz Thanks for the extra information, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to crate different controllers for different module like UserController for user module, ForumController for forum module, BookingController for booking module etc.. It's easy to handle your code..

Answer (score 1):

It's all about readability, simplicity, refactoring and design patterns.